# Does a user have to go to a previous update to get to the latest update?

Tags: android, google-play

Assume we have an initial rollout at version `n_0`. Now, assume that I have made `m` updates and am currently on version `n_m`.

If a user is on version `n_m-2`, does this user have to download version `n_m-1` in order to download version `n_m`?

**I am wondering in regards to the `onUpgrade()` method and when to clean it out.**

Comment: If this is a duplicate, please let me know, and I will remove it. I could not find a similar question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play will always update a user directly to the latest version compatible with their device, and not install any intermediate versions.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Is there documentation I can read on this? How do I know when I can safely remove an sql table alteration from an `onUpgrade`?

Comment: The documentation on Google Play updates is here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476 there isn't much. The logic on updates is up to you to work out I'm afraid